# Using MKMapView without map, only overlays

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit

I need map with custom overlays and without showing/loading maps themselves. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been asked a few times now. This is the best answer I've seen: [MkMapView cancel loading google tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317712/mkmapview-cancel-loading-google-tiles/10702022#10702022)